# What is a super universe?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

I'm reading this well-known paper [*On Universes in Type Theory*](http://www2.math.uu.se/~palmgren/universe.pdf).
At first I expected something similar to `Setω` in Agda, but it turns out that it's even something more general.
It seems to generalize the universe construction from a plain inductive-recursive type to a binder (similar to $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$).
The main question I want to ask is, what's the intention behind it?

Here's some Idris code defining usual Tarski-style universes:

```
mutual

  public export data U : (level : Nat) -> Type where
    GroundU : Ground -> U level
    BinderU : Binder -> (a : U level) -> (b : (x : T {level} a) -> U level) -> U level
    UnivU   : U (S level)
    LiftU   : U level -> U (S level)

  public export T : {level : Nat} -> (code : U level) -> Type
```

I'm trying to generalize it into something like

```
mutual

  public export data U : (a : Type) -> (b : (x : a) -> Type) -> Type where
    GroundU : Ground -> U a ???
    ...
```

What should `???` be? The author of the paper just said universes should be closed under set formers.

edit: I think `???` is simply `b` ...

Comment: Are you trying to have more than `Nat`-many universes? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The paper seems to do that.

Comment: I know what's in the paper. What are *you* trying to do? What is your question?

Comment: Well ... I came up with an idea that would make use of `Setω`, so I looked for papers about super universes to see if I can learn something. There are really few papers about it, and this paper is the main one. In order to understand it, I tried to implement it myself. Although now I don't think it would provide insight to my new idea, I still want to understand it.

Comment: I want to know the intention of generalizing universe construction to a binder.

Comment: Hmm could you point to a specific section of the paper that you're asking about?

Comment: Starting from *Universe Operators and Super Universes*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One intention behind having a universe operator and a super-universe closed under it, is to give a type-theoretic version of [large cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal) axioms known from set theory. An [inaccessible cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal) is like a type-theoretic universe. The next interesting kind of cardinal is a [Mahlo cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahlo_cardinal). Speaking intuitively, a Mahlo cardinal is one that has "a whole lot" of inaccessible cardinals below it. What would this be in type-theoretic terms? It ought to be some sort of a universe $U$ with lots and lots of universes in it. This is what Palmgren is addressing when he considers super-universes.

There is also a more practical side to having many universes. It is useful to have inductive-recursive types in type theory, for all sorts of purposes. But they let us define new universes, so the question is *how many*? To get a feel for what Palmgren is doing, instead of shooting for the super-universe right away, try the following sequence of constructions in Agda (using induction-recursion):

1. Define one universe $U_0$, containing (a code of) $\mathbb{N}$ and closed under $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$. This kind of universe corresponds to an [inaccessible cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal).
2. Define an operator $U$ which takes any type $A$ and defines a universe which contains (a code of) $A$ and is closed under $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$. This sort of universe operator is akin to [Grothendieck's axiom of universes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+universe#axiom_of_universes). How many universes can we get by repeatedly applying $U$, starting from $\mathbb{N}$?
3. To get even more universes, we postulate a *super-universe* $V$ which contains lots of universes, as follows:

   - $V$ contains $\mathbb{N}$, and is closed under $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$
   - Given (code of) a type $A : V$ and a family $B : A \to V$, there is a universe $U$, which is an element of $V$, it contains all types of the family $B$, and is closed under $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$.

   How many universes does $V$ contain? Note that we can get a family $B : \mathbb{N} \to V$ such that $B(n)$ is the $n$-th universe, and so $V$ must contain a universe $U_\omega$ which contains all of these. And this is only the beginning!

Comment: Do you identify the $\mathbb{N}$ in the universe with the traditional meta-theoretic index level?

Comment: I guess the answer is indeed "yes"

Comment: I used mathematical notation throughout. In ASCII I would write `nat` instead of $\mathbb{N}$, so it's not meta-theoretic, it's just the type of natural numbers. It doesn't even matter so much that you have `nat`, I just used it as a base type from which we can get started. If I used `bool`, you'd be fine as well (except you would have to go one universe higher to get to infinite types, as the first universe would contain only finite types built from `bool` using $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$).